# Symfony3 search by relations

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want find user by token. I have one to many relations. My doctrine configuration file:

```
AppBundle\UserEntity:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UserEntityRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
        password:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        salt:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
        email:
            type: string
            length: '100'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    oneToMany:
      token:
        targetEntity: TokenEntity
        mappedBy: user
        fetch:  EAGER



AppBundle\TokenEntity:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\TokenEntityRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        value:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToOne:
      user:
        targetEntity: UserEntity
        inversedBy: token
        joinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

I trying search user by token :

UserEntityRepository.php

```
 <?php 

class UserEntityRepository extends EntityRepository 
{
  public function loadUserByToken(string $token)
 {
   $repository = $this->_em->getRepository('AppBundle:UserEntity');
   $user = $repository->findOneBy(['token'=>1]);

   return $user;
 }
}
```

Symfony throw exception :

> You cannot search for the association field
>   'AppBundle\Entity\UserEntity#token', because it is the inverse side of
>   an association. Find methods only work on owning side associations.

What is wrong ? How repair this relations ?  User should have few tokens.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix that you should create a relational query:

```
$user = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->innerJoin('AppBundle:TokenEntity', 't')
    ->where('t.value = :token')
    ->setParameter('token', $token)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: This works ! I thought, that via ->findOneBy should works, but this solution  is fine. Thanks !